# How to use autohotkey to place clipboard text into query string of url

Tags: autohotkey

Here is what I want to do:

```
!f::
Run, browserpath www.example.com?groupid=WANTPASTEDVALUE&exporttype=1&vehicle=34928
return
```

I want to put the value of the clipboard where `WANTPASTEDVALUE` is.

Answer (score 3):

The following builds a URL, from the text you supplied, inserting the clipboard contents where you had `WANTPASTEDVALUE` in your question.

It then sends that URL to your default browser.

```
!f::
    URL := "http://www.example.com?groupid=" . CLIPBOARD . "&exporttype=1&vehicle=34928"
    Run, %URL%
return
```